# Applications crash/never open

Tags: chromium-os

I Just downloaded Phoenix Linux (Puppy) onto my old Asus 1015PE netbook and Chromium crashes on sign in and none of the other applications will open when clicked.

Comment: I doubt that machine has enough RAM to open Chromium properly.

Answer (score 1):

Phoenix Linux is not yet released you have downloaded a Alpha version.

I would suggest downloading a "production" operating system if you don't want bugs.

There are a million things this could be.

If you want a light weight distro why not look at the following:

- LXLE
- Peppermint OS
- Manjaro Linux Xfce Edition
- Bodhi Linux